# Android - ignore parent view touch on child view touch

Tags: android, touch, android-relativelayout

I have a layout like

```
RelativeLayout_Parent
  -> RelativeLayout_Child
```

both views having touch event. 
But when I touch on `RelativeLayout_Child`, touch event for parent is also fired.

How to ignore parent view touch on child view touch?

Comment: set `focusable= "false"` and `enable="false"` for parent layout while touching on child layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple, implement OnTouchListener over your child view, and upon receiving Touch Event just return true fro  child, this will make sure touch event is not propagated to others.

```
    child_view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // this will make sure event is not propagated to others, nesting same view area
            return true;
        }

    });
```